# Increment date stored in a variable by one day

Tags: unix

I have a variable DATE=2015-02-08. I want a variable NEXT_DATE which will store a date value 1 day after this $DATE value.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. StackOverflow is not a site where you can ask for ready made code. Can you please clarify what you have tried yourself? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: Hii thomas, after trying all only  ..i posted here

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the date to a [Julian Date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), add 1, then convert back. Due to the nature of our calendar, this is a bit involved (at least for shell arithmetic). Should the Wikipedia article not be enough, the [calulations are explained here](http://quasar.as.utexas.edu/BillInfo/JulianDatesG.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cold try to convert that time-stamp in UNIX time, add 3600*24 seconds to it, and then convert it back again to your format.